# Unexpected behaviour of double quotes in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've created a variable which looks like this:

```
firstAndLastLines="$(cat /etc/passwd | head -$n | cut -f5 -d':') $(cat /etc/passwd | tail -$n | cut -f5 -d':') "
```

If I print it to the terminal, using `echo $firstAndLastLines`, I get the following output:
`root bin daemon adm lp Privilege-separated SSH Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd daemon Norbert Fogarasi`

But, if I use `echo "$firstAndLastLines"`, I get the following, separated by new lines:

```
root
bin
daemon
adm
lp 
Privilege-separated SSH
Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd daemon

Norbert Fogarasi`
```

I wondered, why is this happening? It does not have to be the same?
`

Comment: Without quotes all whitespaces including newlines are converted to a single space by shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation in *bash* **man**:

> Enclosing characters in **double quotes** preserves the **literal value** of
>   all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \,